DataStore Could Not Save Gui settings
So i have been making my fully based gui font viewer game in roblox, i added a themes option and soon will add a word editor, now lets focus on the themes, the i have 2 themes, default and green, and the path to each of those is
game.startergui.screengui.themeframe.default
game.startergui.screengui.themeframe.gren
when i change between those, it works but when i rejoin the the default theme always shows
really appreciate your help
i tried chatgpt but chatgpt's code never works.

It is important to note that data stores can store any kind of data you want (if you encode it). In your case, it seems that you just want to store a single string, which is the theme that the user has selected. Assuming this is a client-sided application, you will want a remote event to get the theme and one to set the theme. This is because data-stores can only be accessed from the server.
The Roblox documentation has articles on Remote Events and Callbacks and on Data Stores.
Here is some code that I wrote up that handles saving and retrieving data from data-stores through a remote event called GetTheme and a remote function called UpdateTheme, both of which are inside ReplicatedStorage. The script itself should be in ServerScriptService as a server-sided script.
local THEME_DATASTORE_NAME = "Themes"

local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

local themeDataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore(THEME_DATASTORE_NAME)

local getThemeRemoteEvent = ReplicatedStorage.GetTheme
local updateThemeRemoteFunction = ReplicatedStorage.UpdateTheme

-- We want to return true if this was successful, and false if it was not,
-- so that the client can display an appropriate error to the user.
updateThemeRemoteFunction.OnServerInvoke = function(player, theme)
    if theme == "default" or theme == "green" then
        local wasSuccess, result = pcall(function()
            themeDataStore:SetAsync(player.UserId, theme)
        end)

        if not wasSuccess then
            print("Unable to save data to data-store: " .. result)
        end

        return wasSuccess
    end

    return false
end

getThemeRemoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    -- Retrieve the theme that the user saved
    return themeDataStore:GetAsync(player.UserId) or "default"
end)

Edit: It is important to note here that I did not implement any rate limiting, which I would highly recommend. All you would need to do in this case is have a have a table of players and their last theme update / retrieval and make sure that they can only perform that operation after, say, 5-10 seconds.
